# Showing $(f^{-1}∘g^{-1})=(g∘f)^{-1}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> If the functions $f$ and $g$ are both bijections then the in inverse of the composition function $(f∘g)$ will exist. Show that it will be $(f^{-1}∘g^{-1})=(g∘f)^{-1}$
>
> For the proof assume $f:A→B$ and $g:B→C$

Here's the proof I have worked out so far:

From the problem I know that $f(a)=b$ and $g(b)=c$. By definition of inverse relation it's clear to see that $f^{-1}(b)=a$ and $g^{-1}(c)=b$.

The problem is asking me to prove: $(f^{-1}∘g^{-1})=(f∘g)^{-1}$, so:

$$(f^{-1}∘g^{-1}) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(c)) = f^{-1}(b) = a$$

But I can't seem to prove the other side of the expression:

$$(g∘f)^{-1} = g(f(a))^{-1} = g^{-1}(b) ≠ a$$

I happen to also have the solution to this problem, which is as follows:

> So we have that $a = f^{-1}(b) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(c)) = (f^{-1}∘g^{-1})(c)$ by definition of composite.

But this solution makes no sense to me, simply because I can't figure out how to prove $f^{-1}(b) = a$.

Comment: The statement of the theorem is incorrect: if should be $$f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}=(g\circ f)^{-1}$$ if $(g\circ f)(x)=g\big(f(x)\big)$, and it should be $$g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}=(f\circ g)^{-1}$$ if $(g\circ f)(x)=f\big(g(x)\big)$.

Comment: @James Taylor Going off of what Brian said, inverses always reverse order when you take away the parentheses in the composition. You'll see this in analysis as well as algebra.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I copied the problem incorrectly. But I'm still having the same problem. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the expression:

$$(f^{-1} · g^{-1})·(g·f) = f^{-1} · (g^{-1}·(g·f)) = f^{-1} · ((g^{-1}·g)·f) = f^{-1} · (id·f) = f^{-1} ·f) = id$$

$id$ is the identity map.  Associativity property of composition.  Composing the identity function with any function $k$ yields $k$.

http://orion.math.iastate.edu/butler/2011/fall/201/201_hw9.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account [the previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1232348/225744), I wanted to work out the problem in a more verbose manner because I finally feel comfortable with the material.

Suppose there exists $a∈A$ such that $f(a)=b$ and suppose there exists $b∈B$ such that $g(b)=c$. Because $f$ and $g$ are bijections, by the inverse relation we can say that $b=g^{-1}(c)$ and $a=f^{-1}(b)$.

By definition of a composition function, we have that:

$$(f^{-1}∘g^{-1})(c) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(c))) = f^{-1}(b) = a$$

We know from previous theorems that $(g∘f)(a)=c$ is also a bijection and the inverse exists so $(g∘f)^{-1}(c)=a$. Therefore, we have that:

$ a = (f^{−1}∘g^{−1})(c) = (g∘f)^{-1}(c)$